# find by org.w3c.dom.Element object as parameter on org.dom4j.Document (convert org.w3c.dom.Element to org.dom4j.Element)

Tags: java, xml, dom, dom4j

I have a `org.w3c.dom.Document` parsed by `org.dom4j.io.DOMReader`.

I want to search the dom4j DOM document via `org.w3c.dom.Element`.

say, I have a org.w3c.dom.Element that I need to locate on the dom4j document. I don't have any element information except for having the `org.w3c.dom.Element` object as a parameter.

I want something like dom4j `doc.findByDomElement(org.w3c.dom.Element element)` which would return a `org.dom4j.Element`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need isn't provided by dom4j out of the box.
Dom4j allows you to parse an `org.w3c.dom.Document` as an `org.dom4j.Document`, but then you cannot search through the dom4j `Document` by an `org.w3c.dom.Element`; you should do that on your own method. For instance, you can use xpath to search some nodes. Also, dom4j provides `org.dom4j.dom.DOMNodeHelper` class which is a collection of utility methods to do some conversion from `org.w3c.dom` objects to `org.dom4j` objects but I've not found the method you need. Take a look [here](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/dom/DOMNodeHelper.html). In addition, dom4j provides the `org.dom4j.io.DOMWriter` class to do the opposite of `org.dom4j.io.DOMReader`.

When you say:

> I don't have any element information
>   except for having the
>   org.w3c.dom.Element object as a
>   parameter.

Well, I think the Element object contains all the informations that you need to search manually through the dom4j tree.

Finally, I'd like to suggest you to use only one library to handle xml in your code. Do you have any particular needs? Why are you using both `org.dom4j.Document` and `org.w3c.dom.Document`?

Comment: hi basically, the browser in my Java app loads a org.w3c.dom.domDocument. I want communication between org.w3c.dom.domDocument and org.dom4j.dom.Document

Comment: Ok, if you can't change your java app to load an `org.dom4j.Document`, I think you have to write you own methods to do the communication between the two types of `Document`. Also, take a look at `org.dom4j.dom.DomNodeHelper` which could help you.

Comment: I don't understand how comparing nodes and documents using DomNodeHelper can aid in the communication between the two types of document.

Comment: I guess it's just writing a org.w3c.dom element from dom4j. like here I found something I want. http://www.mail-archive.com/dom4j-user@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01941.html

Comment: You're right! You have also a `DomWriter` class in dom4j to do the conversion.